# An open bounty and crossposting

Tags: discussion, bounty, mathoverflow

I posted a question in MSE and offered a bounty on it.

A few days have passed and I didn't get constructive answers. I know that it is not such a long period, but I also believe this question might have a more proper audience in MO.

So my question is: Can I crosspost a question with an active bounty to MO (after I of course edit it to state I've crossposted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way, as this time, is to post it on MO manually, and setting a bounty there.

Comment: Actually I meant: Can I crosspost a question, that currently has an active bounty in MSE, to MO? (not necessarily having a bounty there) From your answer I gather that it is fine, right?

Comment: Well, it's a free internet (for now). But I would still recommend waiting out the bounty period.

Comment: The wait has proved itself, I got a great answer without crossposting.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!